# How to specify a List<MyCustomType> as a “Return Type” for a UML Interface Property

Tags: user-interface, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2007

I initially posted this question in Stack Overflow, but I have a feeling that I should have posted here instead.

In my Visio 2007 UML document I am unable to figure out how I can add an operation to an Interface that returns a generic `List<MyCustomType>` type.

For example:

Say I have a class named "MyClass" and an Interface named "IFace". IFace has a signature of a method that returns a Generic List of MyClass.

For clarity, here's an example of the C# code:

```
namespace StackO
{
    public interface IFace
    {
        List<MyClass> SomeMethod(string data);    
    }

    public class MyClass
    {
    }
}
```

Here's a screenshot of where I'm stuck:
[image]

It seems as though the only way to specify a `List<MyClass>` as my Return Type is to create another user-defined datatype that is explicitly written as `List<MyClass>`. If this is the case, so be it. However, I'm posting this in hopes that there is a better/proper way to do this.

How can I define the Return Type of an Operation of a Visio Interface to be a Generic List of a User-Defined Datatype?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I received a sufficient answer from my post over at Stack Overflow:

> There is a tip for handling this.
>
> in the Class diagram properties > Go to operations > select the return
>   type you are interested in changing and click properties.
>
> in the next dialog you will have option for setting prefix (List< )
>   and suffix (>).
>
> This way you can specify the return type as List<>.
>
> I see this option in 2010. But I am not sure this option is available
>   in Visio 2007.
>
> I hope this helps.
>
> Regards, Ramana Akula.